# Using ob_ stuff inside a function and call it more than once

Tags: php, function, ob-start

I just discovered, with my great surprise, that I can't use ob_ functions inside a user defined function and call this function more than once, because the second output never comes out

Here are my simplified files

index.php

```
function foo($data){
    ob_start();
    require_once("tpl.php");
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    return $html;   
}

echo foo('Hello');
echo foo('World!');
```

tpl.php

```
<p>and now I say... <?php echo $data; ?><p>
```

I'd expect this output:

```
and now I say... Hello
and now I say... World!
```

Instead, I get only this:

```
and now I say... Hello
```

Where am I wrong? Is there something I'm missing? I'm with PHP 5.3... 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `_once` part. Replace:

```
require_once("tpl.php");
```

with:

```
replace("tpl.php");
```

or:

```
include("tpl.php");
```

Else, you only use the template file once.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! The "_once" part is REALLY "once-and-never-again", I'll remember!